# Monitoring the domains/URLs a Windows application connects to

Tags: windows-7, network-monitor

I am using several Windows applications of which I would like to know which web addresses (usually rather: domains) they are contacting, once I've allowed Windows firewall to let them pass through.

Is there a software that allows me to watch or log network traffic? That is, log the URLs/domains that the application connects to. Ideally, I would like to  restrict/filter against a certain .exe/.dll/process on the client side?

Comment: What are you using for DNS?  I can see DNS requests that all machines on my LAN make, using BIND9 on a raspberry pi running raspbian-wheezy

Answer (score 2):

May not be the exact thing you're after, but [NirSoft CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) might help

[image: CurrPorts]

Answer (score 0):

From the [python](https://www.python.org/) library [psutil](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) you can iterate through the running processes to identify the one(s) that you are interested in and then use the [process.connections](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.connections) method on one or more specific processes. Each time that this is called it gives you a list of the connections opened by the process with details such as connection type and remote address.

The remote address information is in the form of an IP address and a port but the built in `socket` library has a `gethostbyaddr` method that can resolve IP addresses to host names but note that some IP addresses do not reverse DNS very well.

Given the above you should be able to write a little script that when launched with the name of the program finds the PID of that program and sits logging the connections every so often until the program terminates then exits.

Comment: ugh.. thanks, but I was hoping for some already existing software tool which can assist with that... x-) Thanks anyway for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Check for the [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/). Once run, the app tries to redirect all web traffic via its local proxy service which can give you all URLs which all web browsers are trying to connect to. Normally it should work automatically. If it won't, you'll need to configure app to point to that local proxy.

[image]

Otherwise you would need to use some more sophisticated network sniffer such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).